# Cython: storing unicode in numpy array

Tags: numpy, unicode, cython

I'm new to cython, and I've been having a re-ocurring problem involving encoding unicode inside of a numpy array.

Here's an example of the problem:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cpdef pass_array(np.ndarray[ndim=1,dtype=np.unicode] a):
    pass

cpdef access_unicode_item(np.ndarray a):
    cdef unicode item = a[0]
```

Example errors:

```
In [3]: unicode_array = np.array([u"array",u"of",u"unicode"],dtype=np.unicode)

In [4]: pass_array(unicode_array)
ValueError: Does not understand character buffer dtype format string ('w')

In [5]: access_item(unicode_array)
TypeError: Expected unicode, got numpy.unicode_
```

The problem seems to be that the values are not real unicode, but instead numpy.unicode_ . Is there a way to encode the values in the array as proper unicode (so that I can type individual items for use in cython code)?

Comment: If you want to use Python `unicode` objects in your Cython code, the easiest way would be to give the Numpy array an `object` dtype. If you want to keep a fixed-length Unicode array, maybe somehow you could use [PyUnicode_FromUnicode](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_FromUnicode) where necessary?

Answer (score 2):

In Py2.7

```
In [375]: arr=np.array([u"array",u"of",u"unicode"],dtype=np.unicode)

In [376]: arr
Out[376]: 
array([u'array', u'of', u'unicode'], 
      dtype='<U7')

In [377]: arr.dtype
Out[377]: dtype('<U7')

In [378]: type(arr[0])
Out[378]: numpy.unicode_

In [379]: type(arr[0].item())
Out[379]: unicode
```

In general `x[0]` returns an element of `x` in a numpy subclass.  In this case `np.unicode_` is a subclass of `unicode`.

```
In [384]: isinstance(arr[0],np.unicode_)
Out[384]: True

In [385]: isinstance(arr[0],unicode)
Out[385]: True
```

I think you'd encounter the same sort of issues between `np.int32` and `int`.  But I haven't worked enough with cython to be sure.

---

Where have you seen `cython` code that specifies a string (unicode or byte) dtype?

http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html has expressions like

```
# We now need to fix a datatype for our arrays. I've used the variable
# DTYPE for this, which is assigned to the usual NumPy runtime
# type info object.
DTYPE = np.int
# "ctypedef" assigns a corresponding compile-time type to DTYPE_t. For
# every type in the numpy module there's a corresponding compile-time
# type with a _t-suffix.
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
....
def naive_convolve(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] f):
```

The purpose of the `[]` part is to improve indexing efficiency.

> What we need to do then is to type the contents of the ndarray objects. We do this with a special “buffer” syntax which must be told the datatype (first argument) and number of dimensions (“ndim” keyword-only argument, if not provided then one-dimensional is assumed).

I don't think `np.unicode` will help because it doesn't specify character length.  The full string dtype has to include the number of characters, eg. `<U7` in my example.

We need to find working examples which pass string arrays - either in the cython documentation or other SO cython questions.

---

For some operations, you could treat the unicode array as an array of `int32`.

```
In [397]: arr.nbytes
Out[397]: 84
```

3 strings x 7 char/string * 4bytes/char

```
In [398]: arr.view(np.int32).reshape(-1,7)
Out[398]: 
array([[ 97, 114, 114,  97, 121,   0,   0],
       [111, 102,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [117, 110, 105,  99, 111, 100, 101]])
```

Cython gives you the greatest speed improvement when you can bypass Python functions and methods.  That would include bypassing much of the Python string and unicode functionality.