# Cython, how to correctly use a numpy array of string as an input for function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, cython, cythonize

I am trying to use a NumPy array of strings as an input for a cython function. However, I can't seem to figure out how to actually use a numPy array of strings with cython.

Here is an example of the array I am trying to use as an input for my function:

```
np.array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar'])
```

**Attempt 1:**

```
#cython: language_level=3
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

def test_print(np.ndarray[str, ndim=1] unique_product_uids_np):
    cdef str key
    for key in unique_product_uids_np:
        print(key)
```

The above code compiles but when you try and use the function, you get the following error

```
arr = np.array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar'])
does_this_work.test_print(arr)
```

> Does not understand character buffer dtype format string ('w')

**Attempt 2:**

```
#cython: language_level=3
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

def test_print(np.ndarray[np.str_, ndim=1] unique_product_uids_np):
    cdef np.str_ key
    for key in unique_product_uids_np:
        print(key)






Error when compiling:
    def test_print(np.ndarray[np.str_, ndim=1] unique_product_uids_np):
                                    ^
    does_this_work.pyx:6:33: Invalid type.
```

I did the exact same test for `unicode` and got the same results as above. where `unicode` compiled but threw the `Does not understand character buffer dtype format string ('w')` and `np.unicode_` didn't compile and threw the `Invalid type` error while compiling.

Here is what my `setup.py` file looks

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(ext_modules = cythonize('does_this_work.pyx', annotate=True),
      compiler_directives={'language_level' : "3"},
      include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
```

and here is the command I am using to compile:

`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

I am using:
Python version 3.10,
Cython version 0.29.33,
NumPy version 1.24.2

Note: there are a few other post about this but none of the post really resolve the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698179/cython-storing-unicode-in-numpy-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954725/valueerror-does-not-understand-character-buffer-dtype-format-string-w?noredirect=1&lq=1)